# NullPointerException: SetOnClickListener in Fragment Class

Tags: android, fragment

I facing a problem when i add setOnClickListener for ImageView in the Fragment Class. The error occur when i click on the ImageView due to NullPointerException.

Below is my code:

```
public final class TestFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ImageView image = new ImageView(getActivity());
    image.setTag(mContent);
    image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        HomeActivity h = new HomeActivity();
        String url = h.getEventUrl();

        Intent childClass = new Intent(getActivity(), HomeEventDetailActivity.class);

        childClass.putExtra("eventUrl",url);
        TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity)h.getParent();
        parentActivity.startChildActivity("Child_Main1", childClass);
    }
});
    imageManager.displayImage(mContent, image, R.drawable.icon);
    image.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);

    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
    layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    layout.addView(image);

    return layout;
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString(KEY_CONTENT, mContent);

    setUserVisibleHint(true);
}
}
```

Please HELP!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem occurs in this line:

```
ImageView image = new ImageView(getActivity());
```

Instead of passing the fragments host activity as a parameter (via getActivity()) to this constructor, try passing the layout variable which is returned at the end of the onCreateView method.

```
ImageView image = new ImageView(layout);
```

The code would look something like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

ImageView image = new ImageView(layout);
image.setTag(mContent);
image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
    HomeActivity h = new HomeActivity();
    String url = h.getEventUrl();

    Intent childClass = new Intent(getActivity(), HomeEventDetailActivity.class);

    childClass.putExtra("eventUrl",url);
    TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity)h.getParent();
    parentActivity.startChildActivity("Child_Main1", childClass);
}
});
imageManager.displayImage(mContent, image, R.drawable.icon);
image.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
layout.addView(image);
return layout;
```

}